# How can you train your grip to accommodate a wide variety of holding options?

Tags: exercise, training, grip, grip-strength

Based on [this](https://youtu.be/Hb8SIrCsesk?t=662) hand grip, is there a way to train your grip for different holding positions using alternative options not shown in the video? Additionally, is there an exhaustive list available that covers all the grip positions and their respective training exercises?"

Comment: Are you asking about all of the devices shown in the video, or specifically the "hub" device at the timestamp which you linked?

Comment: I ask about both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me personally, I use a [ForceBall](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FVZLE9E) where once you get it going you can adjust your grip to strengthen different positions.

In the past I've also used grippers like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L2XMNK8) to strengthen individual fingers and exercise individualizing the tension.  For example, most people I've met (myself included right now) can't contract their pinky-finger without also contracting the ring-finger but when I was using it more, I could contract my pinky fully without my ring-finger contracting at all.